# MVC3 Display Templates Truncate String

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, display-templates

I have created a custom Display For template that will be used mainly in my index file so that when the records are shown in the lists, they are not turned into ugly looking creature if some records are way too lengthy. I have tried following:

```
@model string

@{
    string text = Html.Encode(Model??"");
    if (text.Length >= 35)
    {
        text = text.Substring(0, 35)+"...";

    }    
    @Html.DisplayFor(model=>text) 
 }
```

Though it works fine for the strings having length more than 35 or equal to it, but it doesn't work if the string is lesser than that. I have tried the else statement, but it doesn't work either. 
What is the correct way to do this?

Edit: Null string. In the source page file, between the two  there is nothing.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? "but it doesn't work" what does it mean? Exception, Empty result, etc?

Comment: Empty results, yes. No exceptions or errors.

Comment: Could it be that the Model is null?

Comment: @Jeff Like I said, it works fine if the string length is more than 35 (or any specified digits).

Comment: I ask because of this: `Html.Encode(Model??"");`, which may cause `text` to be empty.

Comment: If it were empty, then how would I be checking the length and then having the records altered to only show specified characters with the ending dots '...' That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I think your tool here is CSS truncate. Read here for more info http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for the template

```
@model string
@{
    string text = Html.Encode(Model ?? "");
    if (text.Length >= 35)
    {
        text = text.Substring(0, 35) + "...";
    }    
}
@text
```